# Retornar página anterior adicionando parâmetro na URL - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoa, estou quebrando a cabeça aqui e não consegui uma solução. 
O que preciso é o seguinte.

Se um usuário acessar uma url por ex: `www.site.com.br/produto` ele deverá ser redirecionado à uma outra página com uma especie de login ex: `www.site.com/login`.

Se ele fizer o login queria que o usuário fosse redirecionado para a página anterior, porém adicionando o seguinte paramêtro no fim da URL: `?id=CS`
No exemplo que dei ficaria então: `www.site.com.br/produto?id=CS`

```
window.location.href = '/?id=CS';
```

O código acima redireciona apenas para a página inicial, porém queria que ele voltasse para a página anterior que ele tentou acessar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o [document.referrer](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) você tem acesso a página anterior. Mas lembre-se esse comando utiliza as informações do navegador então se você foi redirecionado do *Google.com* > seu site ele vai retornar para o *Google.com?id=CS*

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?id=CS") == -1) {
   window.location.href = document.referrer+'?id=CS';

}
else{
   //não faça nada 
}
```

Comment: Vou fazer um teste e ja retorno

Comment: @FredericoMoreira blz

Comment: @FredericoMoreira deu certo? se sim marque como correta por gentileza

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: Leonardo, poderia me ajudar em uma outra coisa. Estou com o seguinte problema. Se a url anterior já tiver ?id=cs nela, o sistema está adc outra no final, fazendo com q a pagina não abra. Como eu poderia verificar a URL antes de acrescentar? Por ex, se existir o "?id=CS" eu nao adicionaria nada na url ou adicionaria &id=cs

Comment: @FredericoMoreira pronto, usando o `indexOf` passando a string que vocÊ quer encontrar dentro da url, ele retorna o index, se for -1 quer dizer que ele não encontrou, da uma olhada na edição

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso eu precisaria saber se existe na URL do document.referrer que é a url anterior a que estamos no momento. É só eu trocar o window.location.href?

Comment: E tem outro problema, imagine que a url anterior tenha outro parametro, ex: site.com.br?teste=1 na verdade eu precisaria saber se existe um parametro na url pq se existir eu teria que adc era &id=CS ou inves de ?id=CS